# Can I use serialization with obfuscation?

Tags: android, serialization, obfuscation, proguard

I wonder if it will work... In my app I have an object that I'm serializing to file, and then I obfuscate the code with the [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) and application goes to Market. Then I want to release new version of app. I do the same. The users run through the application update.

The question is - does the object, that was serialized with the first version of app, deserialize properly in the second one? And if yes - why?

Comment: Do you really need serialization? Is this not something you could handle with a database or custom file format?

Comment: @jcm, what I really need is to protect this data from unauthorized reading. And if you tell me that user has no right to see database - I'm even afraid of users that will use root privileges to get/analyze/modify that data. So I serialize it with encryption. But maybe own file format would be better, as you say.

Comment: If you want secure *data*, not just its structure, you need encryption. (Of course I'm not sure if there's a way to securely store a crypto key on Android, but it should be enough to foil casual attacks.)

Comment: @Inerdia Yes, I need both obfuscation and encryption. Unfortunately model can change from version to version and it is highly important to keep data so I ended up with jcm advice and made my own file format.

Comment: And the answer for this question is that most likely it will not deserialize properly if you won't make manual mapping for these classes and package names.

Comment: Proguard has a clear [example](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/examples.html#serializable) how to configure for `Serializable` so the special fields and methods shall not be obfuscated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could find several mechanisms ([serialPersistentFields](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#6250), [ObjectInputStream#readFields](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readFields%28%29)) that make it possible for customised serialisation to be dependent on field names - assuming the default mechanism isn't already. The [ProGuard documentation](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#serializable) has some example configuration that shows how to make ProGuard ignore field names and all special methods and fields used by serialisation.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Now I'm thinking that these classes will be not obfuscated. Am I right? Is there any way to obfuscate these classes "manually" using ProGuard?

Comment: You could obfuscate the class and field names manually for serializable classes, I'm just not sure if that's much help. An attacker could just inspect the serialized data and make a guess from that at what the structure and meaning is.